# batch echo pipe symbol causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable in my batch file and it contains the pipe symbol (this one: |) so when I echo the variable I get an error about a unrecognized internal/external command.

I need a way to either get it to echo it correctly or better yet remove everything after and including the | symbol as well as any extra spaces before it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are several special characters that generally must be escaped when used in Windows batch files.  Here is a partial list: `< > & | ^ %`

The escape character is `^`.  So to get a literal `|`, you should do this:

```
echo ^|
```

When the special character is in a variable, it becomes a bit harder.  But if you use special syntax, you can replace characters in a variable like this:

```
set X=A^|B

REM replace pipe character with underscore
set Y=%X:|=_%

echo %Y%
REM prints "A_B"
```

Comment: If you are dealing with filesystem paths from the user/users system, it is pretty much impossible to correctly escape your way to something without special characters. (Filenames can contain %,!,^,& etc)

Comment: Something to note is that doing ^% doesn't work, for %es you need to escape with another % (i.e. use %%).

Answer (score 7):

You must escape the | character before you print the var. The following prints a|b

```
@echo off

set x=a^|b
echo %x:|=^|%
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is the only "real" solution for the problem "output variable which (possibly could) contain a pipe" - and actually something a "secure" script may should always do...

Answer (score 4):

The question did not specify the OS. For unix:

escape it

```
echo \|
```

or wrap in quotes

```
echo "|"
```

Comment: I couldnt escape it as the variable came from another command, quotes worked though... why didn't I think of that before...

Now to see if I can get all the unwanted data removed instead...

Comment: Putting quotes around it will cause the quotes to be output, though.

Comment: I actually was thinking unix when i wrote this, so it's pretty fail!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but there is one unmentioned solution, much easier to use:
**Delayed Expansion**

Using delayed expansion has the advantage, that any content can be used without modifications, there aren't any problematic characters at all.

```
set "test=A|B&C,D"E^<F^>G"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !test!

set test       --- Works, but shows also: "test=..."
echo %test% --- This one fails
```

Comment: Your example still doesn't make a ton of sense to me, but delayed expansion was the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
set X=%0^|callset.bat
set Y=%X:|=_%
echo %Y%
echo %X% _ %Y%
REM activate callset | more
```

REM and you should have infinite pipe. Break CTRL+C twice Ctrl Break
REM prints "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe."

Answer (score 0):

[Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559399/2096401) works fine if you simply want to echo the contents of a variable to the screen, but if you want to pipe a value containing a pipe symbol into another program (as I did) you need to add more carets (`^`):

#### Echo bare text containing a pipe (`|`):

```
echo Hello ^| world
```

#### Set-and-echo variable containing a pipe (`|`):

```
set txt=Hello ^| world
echo %txt:|=^|%
```

#### Echo bare text containing a pipe (`|`) *into another program*:

```
echo Hello ^^^| world | hexdump
```

produces:

```
000000   48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 7c 20 - 77 6f 72 6c 64 20 0a     Hello | world .
```

#### Set-and-echo variable containing a pipe (`|`) *into another program*:

```
set txt=Hello ^| world
echo %txt:|=^^^|% | hexdump
```

produces:

```
000000   48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 7c 20 - 77 6f 72 6c 64 20 0a     Hello | world .
```

(`hexdump` is just a utility I have to dump `stdin` in hex and ASCII).

The reason three carets (`^^^`) are needed (as I think I understand it) is because CMD essentially parses the command-line twice: once to identify that it contains an un-escaped pipe (the `| hexdump` bit); then each part gets processed a *second time* as it goes to execute them.

The first pass turns `echo Hello ^^^| world` into `echo ^| world` (read the middle bit as `^^` followed by `^|`: an escaped caret and an escaped pipe). When it is processed the *second* time – while executing the pipeline – the "surviving" caret protects the pipe symbol so that `Hello | world` is fed into the next command.