# How to create text file using sql script with text "|"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

if i run below script without char "|" it working but when i am adding char "|" it is not working 
how to add char "|" using sql script to text file ?

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Text = 'Hello world| '
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\AppTextFile.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of `|` in your query?

Comment: i want to add data in text file in format

Comment: like data1 | message | date

Comment: any help ? appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pipe character has a special meaning in batch commands, so it must be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855009/batch-echo-pipe-symbol-causing-unexpected-behaviour) using the caret character. This should work:

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Text = 'Hello world^| '
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\AppTextFile.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

Although this is really not a good way to write data to a text file: usually SQL Server should not have permission to write to the root of the C: drive, and `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default. I suggest you look at alternatives like `sqlcmd.exe`, `bcp.exe` or a small script in your preferred language (PowerShell, Perl, Python, whatever).

It is generally much easier, safer and more flexible to query data from SQL Server than it is to push it out from the server side. In your specific case, it looks like you want to write out a delimited file, and [`bcp.exe` is intended for that purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad practice. This could be used from a stored procedure, to produce a set of files. SQL Server shouldn't have permissions to write anywhere, but it is fine to give it permissions to write a specific directory.

Answer (score 4):

Other way to do this

```
DECLARE @File  varchar(300) = 'c:\Temp\out.txt'
DECLARE @Text  varchar(8000) = 'Sample text'
DECLARE @OLE            INT 
DECLARE @FileID         INT

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLE OUT 
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @File, 8, 1 
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @FileID 
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
```

Check for errors using SP result

```
EXECUTE @result = sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @File, 8, 1
if @result<>0 GOTO ON_ERROR
```

Haven't found the way to read error message though

Comment: Much better solution if your `@Text` contains lots of characters that don't fit nicely into the command prompt.  If you're hitting permission issues with `sp_OACreate` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873229/930393)

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with two pairs of single quotes,

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @Text = '''Hello world| '''
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\AppTextFile.txt'
EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

Comment: ''' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NULL

Comment: '"Hello world| "'  is working but i dont want " " in text file

Comment: how should `@cmd` looked like?