# SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

> SQL Server blocked access to procedure `sys.sp_OACreate` of component
>   'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is turned off as
>   part of the security configuration for this server. A system
>   administrator can enable the use of 'Ole Automation Procedures' by
>   using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ole
>   Automation Procedures', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server
>   Books Online.

I tried to enable Ole Automation Procedures as:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 

GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE;
```

When I am executing query, I'm successfully getting output. But when trying through windows forms, I'm getting this error. Please help me

Comment: [Sql Server Blocked access tot procedure](http://sqlsolace.blogspot.com/2009/09/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure.html) I did a google search on your error what's preventing you from doing the same.. here is the link

Comment: What does this return: `SELECT value_in_use FROM sys.configurations
  WHERE name = 'Ole Automation Procedures';`? Did you try using `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`?

Comment: Here, I can send sms by executing the query, but when tried through windows forms, I,m getting this error.

Comment: Well first let's figure out what on earth you're "solving" with sp_OA anyway. This might seem like a valid approach in SQL Server 2000 but there are much better ways to do whatever you're doing and still not have to use the buggy, memory leak-y and deprecated sp_OA procedures.

Comment: ^^ @AaronBertrand: Im trying to send sms using query by calling an API. when executing through query, Im hetting the output. But when tried though windows forms in C#, Im getting above error. Hope you get me

Comment: CLR is a much better option than sp_OA. http://jethvamohit.blogspot.com/2010/03/clr-stored-procedure-calling-external.html

Answer (score 40):

The following example shows how to view the current setting of OLE Automation procedures.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures';
GO
```

The following example shows how to enable OLE Automation procedures.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 15):

Try to run this 3

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO 
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
RECONFIGURE;
```

Answer (score 11):

The Ole Automation Procedures option is also configurable through the SSMS by right-clicking the server instance of interest, select Facets to open the View Facets dialog. On the General page, in the Facet drop-down list, select "Surface Area Configuration" . OleAutomationEnabled is an option in the list of Facet properties displayed. True = On.  (Depending on what you're doing, you may also need the XPCmdShellEnabled setting enabled.) As others have written, I'm not suggesting that one *should* enable this setting, just how to do it through the interface.

Answer (score 10):

Enabling the Ole Automation procedures is only part of the problem.  You need to grant execute:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON master..sp_OACreate to [??]
GRANT EXECUTE ON master..sp_OASetProperty to [??]
GRANT EXECUTE ON master..sp_OAMethod to [??]
GRANT EXECUTE ON master..sp_OADestroy to [??]
```

[??] must be a user/role with access to master.

Comment: Did that but not worked do you have any suggestions?