# how to get and store data from 3rd party xml web service into sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures

Is there any way to get and store 3rd party Web Service XML  data directly into SQL Server DB?

I know there is a lot of other easy solutions like Rest or WCF but in my case I want to add new job to SQL that will trigger every day and get the data from the Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to some resources and get XML response you can use this code:

```
DECLARE @URI nvarchar(max) = 'http://example.com/',
        @methodName nvarchar(50) ='GET',
        @objectID int,
        @setTimeouts nvarchar(255) = 'setTimeouts(9000,90000,900000,9000000)'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @ObjectID OUT

EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false' 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, @setTimeouts
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null 

INSERT INTO SomeTable (xmlResponse)
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText'

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objectID
```

You can comment `@setTimeouts` part, it is needed if response time may be big.

Put this in stored proc. Pass `@URI` as parameter and this will write response in `SomeTable`. Then you can put `EXEC YourStoredProv @URI` into job and schedule each day launch.

**EDIT**

With authorization:

```
DECLARE @URI nvarchar(max) = 'http://example.com/',
        @auth nvarchar(max),
        @methodName nvarchar(50),
        @objectID int,
        @setTimeouts nvarchar(255) = 'setTimeouts(9000,90000,900000,9000000)'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @ObjectID OUT

SELECT  @auth= @URI + 'AppEngine_2/api_login?user_name=myuserName&password=myPassword%20&TOKEN=chinaurl&CLIENT_TYPE=1%22',
        @methodName='POST'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @auth, 'false' 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null 

SELECT  @methodName='GET'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false' 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, @setTimeouts
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null 

INSERT INTO SomeTable (xmlResponse)
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText'

EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objectID
```

You can pass `myuserName`, `myPassword` and `TOKEN` as variables as URL to get response.

Comment: sorry but not working for me...
let me be more specific
i have 2 url's - first for login and the second for the data 
login url = "http://traffilog.com/AppEngine_2/api_login?user_name=myuserName&password=myPassword%20&TOKEN=chinaurl&CLIENT_TYPE=1"

and data url ='http://traffilog.com/AppEngine_2/API_GETDATA'

Comment: And? you can use this code to authorize. Take a look to the edit.

Comment: getting this error, it seems like the 3rd party block it 
SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server

Comment: See this question and answer to enable features [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052815/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure-sys-sp-oacreate-of-component-ole-autom#37725889)

Comment: yes, but its not working... thanks anyway, i did it with ajax request