# Enabling 'Ole Automation Procedures' in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

We are trying to enable 'Ole Automation Procedures' in Linux version of SQL Server 2019 and we tried everything what is advised to do and for example descried in this post: [SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052815/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure-sys-sp-oacreate-of-component-ole-autom)

However we are getting:

> Msg 15392, Level 16, State 2, Server server-name, Procedure SP_CONFIGURE, Line 166
> The specified option 'Ole Automation Procedures' is not supported by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.

We tried Developer and Evaluation editions.

Please advise how to enable Ole Automation Procedures in Linux version of SQL Server 2019.

Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few features that depend on functionality in the Windows OS - these are not supported in the linux version.

Comment: [Unsupport features on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported) include system extended stored procedures, which includes `sp_OA*` system extended stored proceduures.