# Connecting to API via Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue connecting to any API via SQL Server using the OA methods.

The code below is working on one of our servers (MS SQL Server 2019) but not another server (MS SQL Server 2012), both are on an internal ICN. The actual API is also on our ICN but I am having the same issue with the below tester.

On success I'm getting the XML, and by "not working" I just get a blank value with no error

I'm sure there is some setting I'm missing but not sure what to check. I have enabled the OLE Automation procs as per this question: [SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052815/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure-sys-sp-oacreate-of-component-ole-autom)

In other questions people have suggested not using SQL, but for various corporate reasons I am constrained so please keep in mind

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);

DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(255) = 'https://apps.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 @URL,
                 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

SELECT @ResponseText

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: *"Having an issue connecting to any API via MS SQL server using the OA methods"* This was your first mistake, using the OA Methods, *don't*. They are old and outdated, and really there for compatibility purposes. Ideally, use middleware to connect to the API and then have it send that data to SQL Server (or read the data from SQL Server and then send it to the API). If you "must" do it in SQL Server, create CLR functions.

Comment: @ThomA Can you provide more info on CLR functions? I'm not familiar

Comment: You'll be best off with your favourite search engine for information, @JAM . There is *plenty* to read on them, including the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @ThomA Unfortunately the problem is "I don't know what I don't know", OAP seems very straight forward and I'm not aware of CLR even conceptually. Not looking to be spoon fed but high level why go one way over the other?

Comment: As I mentioned, I would go with middleware; only go with CLR if you "must" do this in SQL Server (which is, in truth, unlikely). What you use for middleware is up to you. Powershell, Python, a .Net (console) application, there are plenty of options.

Comment: @ThomA I'll give more context if it helps, for the middleware route I will eventually switch to Python or similar as we are moving to GCP. However that environment won't exist until months from now so I'm stuck with SQL. There are other corporate reasons I'm limited to doing in SQL, it's not ideal but until GCP exists I need to find a solution. So like to understand why is CLR better practice than OAP?

Comment: Is stated this in my original comment *"They [the OA methods] are old and outdated, and really there for compatibility purposes."* So if, for some reason, you'll unable to use an external language (which again includes PowerShell, which the host will certainly have access to), you'll want to go down the CLR route.

Comment: You should write the exact error you're getting. Also, all SP_OA-procedures return an error code which you should check

Comment: @ThomA Respectfully, if you mind adding an answer to the question with details of another method. I'm genuinely unsure of which direction to go and your suggestion of "just Google it" isn't super helpful

Comment: @siggemannen Fair point updated question, no error message just blank value on one server but seeing XML successfully on other server for same code

Comment: OK, like i said, did you check the return values of the procedure calls? Something like: `declare @retval int exec @retval = sp_oa_abc...  if @retval > 0 raiserror('Oa call failed with %d', 11, 11, @retval)`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding @ResponseText is the totality of the response and completely blank, when wrapping in a try catch I get no error
```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
```

Comment: Sigh, i give up. See the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for answer, and how he handles @hr variable to check for errors

Comment: I've added a dupe for CLR as well. If you are stuck at a specific point in that implementation then ask a new question specific to where you got stuck.

Comment: If it works on 2019, you have an easy fix, especially because **SQL Server 2012 has been fully end of life for several years**. That means it no longer gets any updates... **not even critical security patches**. It's irresponsible and dangerous to still be using it. Upgrading this server should be **JOB #1**, and once you do that, **this whole issue becomes moot.**

Comment: @siggemannen I've checked and there are no errors, just blank response. I'll check out those CLR answers thank you

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am aware, we are in the process of migrating to GCP but that doesn't pertain to the question

Comment: What happens if you just open a browser on 2012 server and go to that page?

Comment: Interesting, I get a "Your connection isn't private" warning and if I click through I get a 404. The same link on my local machine works without issue and I can see the XML