# Exporting SQL Server Table to multiple files

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, bcp

I need to export the each selected record in each file with the respective id and username as fileName.

```
| ID | Username | JobType |
| 1  | Ram      | Testing |
| 2  | Raj      | Developer|
```

I need to export all the above as single file for each record which should consist of jobType alone in the text file and the file name as _.txt

I knew BCP,But don't know how to do the above.

For Instance:

```
FileName : Ram_1.txt.
content of the file : Testing
```

Comment: This would be simple with .Net. I am curious to see how it would be done with Bcp. You are referring to command line implementation right?

Comment: yes, This will be a one time usage.

Comment: Like @JoeC says, script it using PowerShell or .NET. Should be the best way to go, or you can even use SSIS. What about here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275493/how-to-create-text-file-using-sql-script-with-text

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old-fashioned way of doing it.

If you really have that simple a set-up, and you only need to do this once, you could generate a batch file to generate the files.

You could do that with this query:

```
 select 'set text = ' + jobType + char(13) 
      + 'Echo %text% > ' + Username + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ID) + '.txt'
 from   MyTable
```

This would give you output that looked like this:

```
set text = Testing
Echo %text% > Ram_1.txt
set test = Developer
Echo %text% > Raj_2.txt
```

Copy that output and paste it into a file called `GenerateFiles.bat`.  Then place that file in the directory you want the output files to appear in.

Double click on it, and it will execute, and you'll have your files.