# How to populate csv file from SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, export-to-csv

How to populate a `.csv` file from a SQL Server stored procedure?

We don't have Office on the Server. The `.CSV` file has to be populated from a stored procedure result set.

How to export to a `.CSV` without using SSIS package?

End result, I will have to generate email alert by attaching this CSV file as report.

I will have to use bulk copy program utility (`BCP`), I am looking on samples for BCP to generate csv file

Comment: Assuming you are wanting something automated.  If you aren't adverse to PowerShell it would be pretty easy to do.

Comment: `bcp` or `sqlcmd`?

Comment: not understaing the quation, you want to create a csv file and save it to the disk using storeprecedure or you want to only convert the table data to csv string then using C# or what ever to create the file

Comment: There is no c# involved.

Comment: ok maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275493/how-to-create-text-file-using-sql-script-with-text

Comment: I will have to use BCP, I am looking on samples for BCP to generate csv file

Comment: Take a peek at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to achieve that:

## (1) Using OPENROWSET

Try implementing a similar logic:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [FileName.csv]')
EXEC Sp_TEST
```

## (2) Using bcp

From the third link in References section:

> The queryout method allows you to BCP from the result of a stored procedure, which opens up a lot of possibilities and offers a lot of control over the file format. For anything other than a simple table extract I would tend to use this method rather than a view. I would also format each line within the stored procedure. This means that the formatting can be tested independently from the file creation

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "exec sp_Test"
   queryout c:\bcp\sysobjects.csv -c -t, -T -S'
+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

---

## References

1. [How To Export Data To the .csv file using Sql server Stored Procedure.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546777/HowplusToplusExportplusDataplusToplustheplus-csvpl)
2. [How to produce an csv output file from stored procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079666/how-to-produce-an-csv-output-file-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)
3. [Creating CSV Files Using BCP and Stored Procedures](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/)
4. [Exporting a csv file via stored procedure](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=104935)
5. [Writing select result to a csv file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below.  A stored procedure is created and then used as the source in the BCP command.  Then a text file is generated.  Delimiters are discussed in the code sample in the link.

Code sample taken from [Creating CSV Files Using BCP and Stored Procedures](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/)

```
use tempdb
go
create proc s_bcpMasterSysobjects
as
   select   '"' + name + '"'
            + ',' + '"' + convert(varchar(8), crdate, 112) + '"'
            + ',' + '"' + convert(varchar(8), crdate, 108) + '"'
   from master..sysobjects
   order by crdate desc
go
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "exec tempdb..s_bcpMasterSysobjects"
       queryout c:\bcp\sysobjects.txt -c -t, -T -S'
+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `BCP`

see example

```
declare @sql varchar(2000)
select @sql = 'bcp "SQL QUERY HERE" queryout '+@fileLocation+@fileName+'.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql, NO_OUTPUT
```

if you need to see any errors or whats it's doing, just remove the `", NO_OUTPUT"`

Comment: Thank you. I am using this syntax to generate the direct output .. exec master..xp_cmdshell N'sqlcmd -E -Q"set nocount on; select top 10 * from testtable;" -s"," -W -o"c:\MyFolder\output.csv"'    Now, when i tried to pass the Stored Procedure with paramater on it such as  ( exec sp_GetReport 'Inboundfile.txt' ) instead of Select query .. i am getting the syntax error

Answer (score -1):

Create a little script, the csv is a simple format : csv = comma separate value. Separate your values width comma.

Comment: This really doesn't address the question. OP is asking how to output to a csv from a stored procedure, not what a csv is.

Comment: @Error_2646 I think this actually addresses the OPs question. OP doesn't seem to know what CSV is and is trying to make a correlation with Office.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, thinking of CSV, can you tell me why would one need Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB on a server at all?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I am not sure you know what you are talking about. Why would I need Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB on a server just to utilize CLR? Probably instead of saying "for example" you should show some solid reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186824/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti,  "peg"? Hope you are not saying something bad to me. It was you all  along who claims one needs ACE.OLEDB for CSV.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That doesn't really improve the answer. "Create a little script" is not going to be helpful for someone who doesn't even know what a .csv is.

Comment: @Error_2646, that is the point, OP doesn't seem to know what CSV is and seeking harder solutions.

Comment: @Cetinbasoz Maybe, based on his profile it seems very farfetched that he wouldn't know and wouldn't be able to figure out what a .csv is, but it's possible.